# Handshake Failure (40) when IIS connects to SoapUi

Tags: wcf, iis, certificate, soapui

I'm creating an app hosted by IIS and I want to have it communicate securely with SoapUi (so IIS is the client is this scenario). I'm using certificates at both ends because I want mutual authentication. When IIS connects to SoapUi, I can see in WireShark that:

1. The *client hello* is sent from IIS
2. Then SoapUi responds with the *server hello* and continues with the certificate and a certificate request
3. Then IIS terminats the connection with a TCP [FIN, ACK]
4. And finally SoapUi sends the **Alert(Level: Fatal, Description: Handshake Failure)**
5. In my application log I can see the error `Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'localhost:8443'.`

From the logs in my app I can see that my app is apparently loading the certificate as expected. The certificate is loaded from the *LocalMachine* certificate store and the CA certificate is located in the *Trusted Root Certification Authorities*. In SoapUi I've added .pfx files for the SoapUi certificate/private key and for the CA certificate/private key. Both the IIS certificate and the SoapUi certificate is signed by the same CA.

Is there anything special I need to configure in IIS to allow an app to connect with mutual certificate authentication.

Comment: You need to make sure that App pool that was running the service have access to the certificate.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-make-x-509-certificates-accessible-to-wcf?redirectedfrom=MSDN

Comment: Thanks, that solved it. I had to give my app pool access to the private key of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

IIS does not necessarily have access to the private keys in the local machine certificate store. If you have installed the certificate with e.g. an administrator account you will have to [give the app pool that runs your application access to the private key of the certificate](https://serverfault.com/questions/131046/how-to-grant-iis-7-5-access-to-a-certificate-in-certificate-store).